# How to create bot test in android

Tags: android, root

I want to create an application that open another application and begins to fill fields type text and select  like  Xmodes in games . This application is for test my application in real mode

I now i need root my divice to do this

Any help please

Comment: If you are trying to test your own app, write test cases, using the testing frameworks and testing tools that ship with the Android SDK. You do not need "an application that open another application" to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it could be helpfull.

ADB has got a command called [UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html).

With this command the ADB will automatically perform random click, slides, input on one of your application activity.

You can set some parameters too if you want to define which kind of input and operation should the monkeys perform.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped!